# Spark SQL - Alternative for 'contains' function

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario wherein I need to find the existence of strings in dataframe column within larger strings in another column of another dataframe.
I am using **Spark 2.4.4** and **Scala 2.11.12**.

Comment: Can you show examples of input dataframes and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` has the contains function that you can use to do string style contains operation between 2 columns containing String.

```
val df = //a dataframe buiktas a result of join and has 2 columns - c1, c2

df.filter(col("c1").contains(col("c2"))).show()
```